# How create a text element in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to add differently colored (and otherwise styled) text strings to a Google Doc. I was thinking of making a Text object for each string, manipulating it and then adding it to the doc, but alas, when calling
`var richText = new Text();`
I get this error: `This constructor cannot be called directly.`

Is there a way instantiate a Text element? If not, how would I go about styling many small pieces of text?

Answer (score 0):

simply use paragraphs.

There is an `appendParagraph('string'`) method and paragraphs have styling and edition methods.

read [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendParagraph(String))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, I want to create the whole string first, and then replace some text in the document with it. I'm not sure how to do it with the `appendParagraph` method, which only appends the text to end of the document.

Comment: First append your string as a paragraph and then manipulate it...you can also use insert paragraph.

Comment: How would I go about placing the paragraph in the document?